# What is wrong with this code in C for SPOJ Prime Generator?

Tags: c

I am a beginner programmer and I started to code 3 months ago. I decided to do problems on SPOJ but i am getting stuck very frequently. I completed the problem 1 i.e Life and universe which was easy but I got stuck in this one. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
int m,n,i,j=2, t,counter=0;

scanf ("%d", &t);

while (t--) {

    scanf ("%d%d", &m,&n);

    for (i=m; i<=n; i++) {

        for (j=2; j<(int)sqrt(i); j++) {
            if (i%j==0) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf ("%d\n", i);
                break;
             }
         }
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

I am unable to figure out what and where I am doing it wrong.

I also tried one different version for this which gives the correct answer but that code is taking very long time and giving TLE . The code is as follow :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
int m,n,i,j=2, t,counter=0;

scanf ("%d", &t);

while (t--) {
    scanf ("%d%d", &m,&n);

    for (i=m; i<=n; i++) {
        while (j<=i) {
         if (i%j==0)
         counter++;
         j++;
        }
        if (counter==1)
        printf ("%d\n",i);
        counter=0; 
        j=2;
    }
 }
return 0;
}
```

How can I prepare myself for SPOJ and other programming competitions? Where I am lacking?

Comment: You are lacking in debugging skills.

Comment: `What is wrong with this code` – for starters, its horribly indented.

Comment: `while` works with booleans, and t-- is an integer being reduced by one. Should work better by using `while (t-- >= 0)` since it's now a boolean result

Comment: @fmbesteiro um nope? those are equivalent if `t` starts out as non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things that might help;

1. as others have suggested learn some debugging skills.
2. learn about algorithms and how to estimate the run-time complexity.
3. In your second example you have the code shown below (comments are mine).  In this code you are trying to determine if `i` is a prime or not by looking for factors of the number.  If `i` is set to five, then the while loop assigns these values to `j`: [2, 3, 4, 5] and we then perform the following 
   modulus operations: `5%2, 5%3, 5%4` and `5%5`.  You do not really need to test if `i` is divisible by itself (isn't that what a prime is?  only divisible by 1 and itself).  You will need to rework the following logic a bit, but you get rid of one modulus operation per iteration through the outer-loop.

   ```
       for (i=m; i<=n; i++)           // outer loop
       {
           while (j<=i)               // inner loop
           {
               if (i%j==0)            // does this work as intended?
                   counter++;
               j++;
           }
   ```
4. Considering the same loop, lets see what happens if `m` is 100 (this means that `i` will start at 100).  What your inner loop will do is calculate the remainder of dividing the test number (*i.e.* `i`) by every number in the range [2,100].  The first modulus operation (100 % 2) will return 0, so we immediately know that 100 is a composite number.  At this point, there is no reason to continue to perform additional tests.  To fix the issues that I've brought up in point 3 and 4, you can rewrite the inner loop as (I've move the initialzation of `j` to the top of the inner loop, and introduced a new variable, `isPrime`):

   ```
       bool     isPrime;
       for (i=m; i<=n; i++)           // outer loop
       {
           j = 2;
           isPrime = true;
           while (j < i)               // range of j is now [2, i)
           {
               if (i%j==0)             // number is a composite
               {            
                   isPrime = false;
                   break;
               }
               j++;
           }

           if(isPrime)            // never found a divisor
           {
                printf ("%d\n",i);
           }
       }
   ```
5. Notice that in points 3 and 4, all I did was ask what happens with small input and see what happens looking for logic errors.
6. Consider doing something other than a brute-force method.  In the problem, you are told `1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000`, so there is probability that you may need to determine if a large number of test cases are prime (*i.e.* n-m = 100,000) or are working with very large test-cases (*i.e.* n = 1,000,000,000).  Given these extremes a brute-force method may be very computationally expensive.  To see this consider that `m = 999,900,000 and n = 1,000,000,000` is a valid range.  This means you might need to look at other methods for primality testing.
7. Don't give up.  Programming is an intellectual exercise, and the only way to get better is to practice, try things, learn from your mistakes (and there will be many).  This is really the only way to get better at programming

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. It's a great one ! Unable to upvote due to no reputation points

Answer (score 0):

For this question, keeping the constraints(value of m and n) in mind, use **Sieve of Eratosthenes** algorithm, a simple, efficient and ancient algorithm for finding all prime numbers up to any given limit.Here is the pseudo code for the algorithm

```
Input: an integer n > 1.

 Let A be an array of Boolean values, indexed by integers 2 to n,
 initially all set to true.

 for i = 2, 3, 4, ..., not exceeding √n:
   if A[i] is true:
     for j = i2, i2+i, i2+2i, i2+3i, ..., not exceeding n:
       A[j] := false.

 Output: all i such that A[i] is true.
```

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes. Hope this helps!